# Genymotion Http Connection in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I try to connect https://stackoverflow.com/about. In command line connection is success . But when i connect with Android Gui+Genymotion , program was broken. Broken line is : urlConn.connect();
Error msg: Unfortunately,Merhaba has stopped.
I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

but i still have a problem. Sorry my bad English.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      String strUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/about";
      try {
          URL url = new URL(strUrl);
          HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          urlConn.connect();
          //System.out.println(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
          //assertEquals(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, urlConn.getResponseCode());
      } catch (IOException e) {
          //System.err.println("Error creating HTTP connection");
          //System.out.println("Hata");
          //throw e;
      }         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 final String strUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/about";

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);
                  HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                  urlConn.connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```